# AWS MQTT over websocket with ngx-mqtt

Tags: angular, websocket, mqtt, aws-iot

The example given on the [aws website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt-ws.html) uses [Paho](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paho-mqtt) and I'm trying to adapt it using [mqtt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) as it seems to have much better adoption. Since I'm working on Angular 6+ I decided to go for [ngx-mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mqtt) which doesn't have great adoption but uses mqtt.js under the hood and seems to provide a convenient observable interface.

1) Is this possible at all or am I going in a dead end? Should I stick with Paho?

2) here's what the devtools network looks like:

- working implementation using Paho [image]
- attempt at using ngx-mqtt [image]
  the urls seem fine but somehow the requests don't show up as using GET, That's the only thing that seems to differ between the two. Any pointer as to what I'm missing?

Here's my configuration:

```
import { MqttModule } from 'ngx-mqtt';
MqttModule.forRoot({ connectOnCreate: false })
...
this.mqttService.connect({ protocol: 'wss', hostname: 'foo', path: '/bar', port: 80 });
this.mqttService.observe('baz');
```

related read:

- [Why use MQTT Node.JS library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189164/why-use-mqtt-node-js-library)

Answer (score 3):

ngx-mqtt works well.
I used ngx-mqtt without problems (i'm lying) in my angular 8 app. For the basic config this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265772/unable-to-connect-to-mqtt-broker-via-ngx-mqtt-in-angular8) may help you: it's my question and i started from [this medium guide](https://medium.com/@anant.lalchandani/dead-simple-mqtt-example-over-websockets-in-angular-b9fd5ff17b8e). (I'm still stuck because i'm over https and mqtt require tls in order to work and i didn't resolved my issue yet).

Regarding the network inspector, of course you are not seeing a 'get' request: those methods are http related and have nothing to do with the socket protocol.

Comment: with angular 10 the 'issue' is resolved, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379281/using-mqtt-ngx-to-connet-in-tls-via-websocket-to-a-broker